# Использование register_next_step_handler в общем чате телеграм

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

подскажите пожалуйста, пишу бота на Python, использую библиотеку pyTelebot.
Есть ли возможность использовать бота в групповом чате телеграм и использовать register_next_step_handler, дело в том что при отправлении команды "updatereason" в общий чат, бот откликается, появляется клавиатура, все отрабатывает. Но боту может ответить любой пользователь который находится в чате. Если ли какая то возможность изолировать цепочку вопросов и ответов в общем чате ? Что бы пользователь обратившийся к боту имел что-то типа своей сессии. Ну или хотя бы бот не реагировал на обращение других пользователей, пока первый пользователь не пройдет всю цепочку вопросов и ответов. Вот мой код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['updatereason']) # Динамические кнопки 
    def send_welcome(message):
        regiddict = {}  #Список региона и id для генерации кнопок (сим без причины)
        noreasonlist = bd.pars_reasonnull().fetchall()
        if len(noreasonlist) != 0:
            for i in range(len(noreasonlist)):
                regiddict[noreasonlist[i][2]] = noreasonlist[i][0]      
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard= True, one_time_keyboard= True, selective=True) 
        for key in regiddict:
            markup.add(types.KeyboardButton(f'{key}'))
        msg = bot.reply_to(message,  "Choose one letter:", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, answerreg,regiddict)
    
    
    
    def answerreg(message,regiddict):
        valuepop = []
        if message.text in regiddict:
            value = message.text
            valuepop.append(regiddict.pop(value))   
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True, selective=True)
            markup.add(types.KeyboardButton('Отмена'))      
            msg = bot.reply_to(message,f"Введите причину!", reply_markup=markup)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, reason, valuepop)

    def reason(message, valuepop): # Апдейтер причины.
        if message.text == 'Отмена':
            valuepop.pop()
            bot.reply_to(message,"Причина не указана, отмена!")
        else:
            bd.reason_updater(valuepop.pop(),message.text)
            bot.reply_to(message,"Причина активации занесена в базу!")

    
        
        

    
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, )
```

Comment: Генерируйте кнопки с разными `callback_data`, которые могут к примеру начинаться на `TEST` после рандомное число и уже ваш `callback_data`, который был ранее прикреплен к кнопке, после сохраняйте данные кнопок в список для отдельного пользователя в базе, после когда кто-то нажмет на кнопку проверяйте есть ли эти `callback_data` у пользователя в базе, если есть выполняете действие, если нет придумайте что угодно

Comment: Кто вызвал команду тот и может выполнять шаги и нажимать на кнопки, и условие простое и записать в память легко